# jquery mobile to display html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and JavaScript. i have some response in a variable that response is a html content .now i have to display this html content in the UI of jquery mobile. That content should appear as a text not as html.

```
jquery("#content").html(wiJson);

<div data-role="content" id="content">
</div>
```

This is what i have used in my code  `jquery("#content").html(wiJson);` this is used in javascript and

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
        </div>
```

is used in jquery mobile ui

Comment: jq("#contentid").html(wijson); this is actually working if i put some html content inside wijson    . but that(wijson) contain html in the form of json .that is making problem

Answer (score 2):

> That content should appear as a text not as html.

Try using .text()

```
jquery("#content").text(wiJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **pre & code** tags to your html and append it using .append() jQuery method. It's gonna look something like this.

```
jQuery('#content").append('<pre><code>wiJson</pre></code>');
```

Hope this helps.